# Sometimes comments don't 'add'

Tags: bug

I've noticed, sometimes comments won't add:

Right now, I'm writing a long comment, so it stretches over two; the first part, posted; but the second didn't - is this a bug or feature?

I mean, a measure to stop people 'ranting' in comments?

Comment: "it stretches over two" - two what? Were you trying to post two comments within seconds of each other?

Comment: Yeah can you clarify exactly step by step what you did?

Comment: I'm wondering if you were adding a comment and "editing" another at the same time?

Comment: @oded: no, not within seconds or minutes between each other; say 10 minutes apart; it's just annoying and irritating when it happens; is only very occasionally, though.

Comment: If a developer can't reproduce the behavior, they can't fix it. The more details you give about what you did when this happened, the exact step taken etc, the easier something like that is to reproduce. If it is something intermittent, it can be on your end, on the Stack Exchange end or somewhere in between.